# Python 3.4 - Downloading newly uploaded text files from pastebin.com

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I want to download text files from pastebin.com.
Once I start the program it should look for text files that are being uploaded and "download" them once they're uploaded.
I know how to "download" them but not how to tell Python to click on one of the public files on http://pastebin.com/archive and then click on the "raw"-button to open a new tab that contains the "raw" content.

I googled a lot but literally nothing came up that would help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a program doesn't know how to "click" anything :). In order to retrieve information from a page, you simply need to send a GET request at the correct url. In your case, that would be http://pastebin.com/raw/4ffLHviP or any other code of the pastebin you want to download. You can retrieve codes manually, or e.g. by applying text parsers (regex, beautifulsoup...) on the [archive page](http://pastebin.com/archive).

Note that, there is an API for scraping Pastebin (see http://pastebin.com/scraping). It is strongly recommended, if you want to extract consequent content from them, to use it. It is more "polite", may offer better service, and will avoid you to be blacklisted.

Comment: Could you please post a code example to collect the specific urls of the text files? :)

Comment: Here is for archive page, it's not going through API so use with caution : http://pastebin.com/HZLKwrqF

Answer (score 1):

To choose a file you simply do the following:

1. Visit the link of the file, ex. *http://pastebin.com/B8A6L7Zt*
2. The raw content is **already** on that page, namely inside`<textarea id='paste_code'>...</textarea>`. So you just cut this content off, using regex for example.
   [image]

Comment: @dsgdfg, most likely you need `html escape`. Example code is [here](http://scraping.pro/using-domxpath-for-parsing-page-content-in-php).

Comment: Okay, thanks, that was helpful, but the "paste_code" is only on the specific page - can you give me a hint on how to go through the list of text files on http://pastebin.com/archive? Maybe a code example?